# JAVA: Put Image in jTable Cell

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable, cell

I need to display an image in one of jTable cells.
I wrote this:

```
class ImageRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel();

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        lbl.setText((String) value);
        lbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/home/ariyan/Desktop/71290452.jpg"));
        return lbl;
    }
}
```

and then used it as this:

```
    jTable1.getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new ImageRenderer());
```

But this didn't work
How I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

JTable already provides a default renderer for images. You just need to tell the table what type of data is contained in each column and it will choose the best renderer:

a) override the getColumnClass() method of the JTable or the TableModel to return the class of data in the column. In this case you should return an Icon.class.

b) add an ImageIcon to the table model.

Now the JTable will use the default Icon renderer for that column.

Comment: How can i do that in netbeans?!

Comment: See also [*How to Use Tables: Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm: `jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new ImageRenderer());` perhaps?

Here's the relevant extract of some quick test code I put together to quickly verify my guess. It displays icons from a folder (it assumes all files in a folder are icons, so you should test it with something like an XDG icon theme sub directory). Install table model first then add the cell renderer on the columns:

```
class Renderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table,
                                                    Object value,
                                                    boolean isSelected,
                                                    boolean hasFocus,
                                                    int row, int column) {
        if(isSelected) {
            this.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            this.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        }
        else {
            this.setBackground(table.getBackground());
            this.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        }
        if(column == 0) {
            this.setText(list[row]);
        }
        else {
            // edit as appropriate for your icon theme
            this.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/usr/share/icons/default.kde4/16x16/apps/"+list[row]));
        }
        return this;
    }

}
class Model extends DefaultTableModel {

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable (int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt (int row, int column) {
        return list[row];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount () {
        return list.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount () {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName (int column) {
        return column == 0? "Name" : "Preview";
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass (int columnIndex) {
        return String.class;
    }
}
// edit base directory as appropriate for your icon theme of choice
static String[] list=new File("/usr/share/icons/default.kde4/16x16/apps/").list();
```

Comment: Renderers should be as efficient as possible. You should not be reading the Image from disk every time the renderer is invoked. Also when extending the default renderer you should invoke super.getTableCellRendererComponent(...). This will make sure the renderer is fully initialized, for example by adding the appropriate border as well as setting the default colouring.

Comment: Of course not. But hey I posted this as concept, prototype code. Not an actual working drop-in solution!